# Firecracker microVM: how to execute a script file when a Firecracker microVM startup?

Tags: firecracker

I went through [Get Start Guide](https://github.com/firecracker-microvm/firecracker/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) and [api_request_doc](https://github.com/firecracker-microvm/firecracker/tree/master/docs/api_requests) to find a way to execute a script when start a microVM? But there is not way to do it.

Is there a way to achieve it? I want to run some script when a vm startup or execute a script without login.

Answer (score 1):

So, far firecracker has not provided any support to start a script on startup.

You can use system daemons like openrc (for alpine based) and systemd to start the script on the startup.

to start script using systemd on startup, check https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux